# How can i use the '&' symbole in a GET parameter

Tags: c#, .net, url, web, url-parameters

I need to create GET parameters containing '&'s without creating new parameters for each '&'s.

**For instance the following URL :**

```
http://example.com/?action=redirect&url=http://web.com/home.aspx?action=add&ref=aaa
```

**will give me :**

```
action = 'redirect'
url = 'url=http://web.com/home.aspx?action=add'
ref = 'aaa'
```

**But I want :**

```
action = 'redirect'
url = 'url=http://web.com/home.aspx?action=add&ref=aaa'
```

It's in the context of a c#.net application and i'd rather not use POST parameters.

Is it even possible ?

Thanks

Comment: The escape character for & in urls is "%26", so replacing it should work fine I think

Comment: Are you using jquery? to generate the url initially?

Comment: Is this url something you're generating or something you are being passed?

Comment: you must be a little clear on how this URL is set, and where are you trying to access the property values.